# How to approach this tree traversal

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, tree, traversal

It has been a while since I have had to do tree traversal and would like some input. Here is a sample tree:

[image: tree]

The tree is my ASP.NET page. This page is made from 2 master pages and the content page. What I want to do is find the control that is my 2nd master page's primary content and then place all the controls inside in a flat data structure such as a list.

So given that the Orange node is the 2nd master page's primary ContentPlaceHolder, I would like to store all those in the blue ellipse in my list. I have already created some code to return me all child, grandchild, etc of a control in a collection with this:

```
private IEnumerable<Control> GetChildControls(Control parentControl)
{
    foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        yield return control;
        foreach(Control grandchild in GetChildControls(control))
        {
            yield return grandchild;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am a bit stuck on how to filter this tree to a node and it's children. If it helps, the orange node should be the following:

```
<asp:Content ID="SystemMasterMainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceholder">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could basically use a combination of the method you already have, and a `GetChildById()` method.

```
private Control GetChildById(string controlId, Control parent)
{
    return GetChildControls(parent).First(c => c.ID == controlId);
}
```

This re-uses the tree traversal that is done by `GetChildControls`. Note that it will throw an exception if the control is not found - if you don't want that, use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.

You could potentially use it like so:

```
GetChildControls(GetChildById("SystemMasterMainContentPlaceHolder", Page));
```